# Que deberia cambiar en el codigo para que me valide el Junit

Tags: java, junit

Codigo:

```
public static boolean validar(String dni) {
    if (dni.length()>9) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
```

-----> JUNIT

```
@Test
void testCamino1() {
    Boolean resultadoEsperado= true;
    Boolean resultadoReal = Examen.validar(9);
    assertEquals(resultadoEsperado, resultadoReal);
}
@Test
void testCamino2() {
    boolean resultadoReal = Examen.validar(7);
    boolean resultadoEsperado= false;
    assertEquals(resultadoEsperado, resultadoReal);
 }

}
```

Ando bastante perdido, porque me pide que meta String y el valor que quiero validar es boolean.
Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Kaly 9Comotuvea puedes utilizar la los siguientes métodos de junit  Assert.assertTrue(); y Assert.assertFalse();

```
 assertTrue(Examen.validar(9));
 assertFalse(Examen.validar(7));

@Test
void testCamino1() {
    assertTrue(Examen.validar(7));
}
@Test
void testCamino2() {
    assertFalse(Examen.validar(9));
 }

}
```

Comment: He probado lo que me has comentado Robert E Morán y nada pero agradezco su consejo, seguire probando.

Comment: Tienes razón, es que me apresure a dar la respuesta, con tu duda "me pide que meta String" es porque tu método validar(String dni) espera un String pero tu le estas enviando Examen.validar(7) que es un numero. Debes de enviar un por ejemplo Examen.validar("A12345678H")